What tags would I use when asking about what makes a game AAA/AA/etc?
I want to ask a question about what makes a game AAA/AA/etc, and what all the “A levels” are (not talking about the English education system).
What tags would I use for this? And if they don’t exist yet, could someone more knowledgeable than me make them, or tell me what to do (I have rep enough for that)?

I'm kind of on the fence on this not being on topic for our site.  It's also potentially subjective.
We do have What is an AAA game? that was asked 14 years ago.  A lot has changed since then, and I am not so sure if a question like that would be on topic if asked today (though it seems to be taking the terminology approach as it is tagged, so I suppose it is on topic).
I would probably say this is better for the Game Development SE site, which already has What defines a AAA game?

For what its worth, I don't think there are really "A" tiers, its really only "triple A", which most people associate as games developed by large studios that have a substantial backing/history (think Grand Theft Auto, Call of Duty, Battlefield, etc.).  Everything else is simply just a game.
